# jQuery hide next element on change

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to hide the next element with a class but I think it's getting confused by the html structure.

html:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="number" value="1" name="product_quantity" class="form-quantity" />
 </td>
 <td><a class="add_to_cart_button" href="#">Add To Cart</a></td>
</tr>
```

js:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
 $(this).find(".form-quantity").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".add_to_cart_button").hide();
 });
});
```

JS Fiddle to see what I mean - https://jsfiddle.net/vpvw6t53/

I have tried using .parent, .children and .sibling so asking here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @barmar for pointing out that my solution wouldn't work in the context with the actual `table`. So I updated my answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-quantity").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".add_to_cart_button").hide();
  });
});
```

Also, you don't need to loop over the `tr` elements so I removed that from the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".form-quantity").change(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".add_to_cart_button").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="1" name="product_quantity" class="form-quantity" />
    </td>
    <td><a class="add_to_cart_button" href="#">Add To Cart</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="number" value="1" name="product_quantity" class="form-quantity" />
    </td>
    <td><a class="add_to_cart_button" href="#">Add To Cart</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is wrong. The button isn't the next element after the input. They're both in different `<td>` elements. The only reason it works in your fiddle is because you left out `<table>`, so the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements are ignored.

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/vpvw6t53/9/ for a version with `<table>`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Since @Barmer 9 explains correctly that the solution is wrong, you should improve it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for pointing that out. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot try it at this moment, but

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".form-quantity").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".add_to_cart_button").hide();
 });
});
```

should work. Keep in mind that you select your Input element.

Comment: I suggest using `.closest("tr")` instead of `.parent().parent()`, to be more flexible.